# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while execution

Tags: hadoop

```
package com.HadoopExpert;


import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;


  public class SumMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text,Text,IntWritable>{


  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    String s = value.toString();
    String[] words = s.split(",");

    String gender  = words[4];
    int sal = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);

    con.write(new Text(gender), new IntWritable(sal));
}
}
```

this is my mapper class code i want to fetch array by index m getting a eror aarray out of bound index
thanx in advance

Comment: Could you please provide what the data in the file that you are reading from looks like?

Comment: keep in mind that numbering starts from 0, not 1. So the fourth element of the array `words` is `words[3]`, and not `words[4]`.

Comment: 101,Ahmed,30000,M,USA,1001
102,sagar,40000,M,India,1002
103,sunita,30000,F,Singapur,1002
104,kishore,30000,M,India,1003
105,nandu,30000,M,India,1004
106,Ahmed,30000,M,India,1005
107,kranti,20000,M,India,1006
108,ravi,80000,M,India,1007
109,Nikita,30000,F,India,1008
110,ayaz,30000,M,malasiya,1006
111,pinky,30000,M,India,1005
101,rafi,70000,M,India,1003
111,mamta,90000,F,canada,1009

Comment: what vefthym said, in your case the gender is in index 3. This is not what causes the error though. I believe what causes the error is that some lines might not have all the fields specified and you should account for that.

Answer (score 1):

According to your data metioned in your comment, the index of gender should be `3`. Note that the index of array starts from `0` in java.

And you should always check your data before use it, such as:

```
if (words.length > 3) {
    String gender = words[3];
    ......
}
```

And you should think about how to process the bad data (count up and then ignore it, or try to fix it, and so on).